# mssql service cannot start, after setup

Tags: sqlserver

After installing mssql-server, it successfully installs then on setting up it fails with the error below

Step one - on setup it fails with the error below

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup 

> Enter the SQL Server system administrator password:  Confirm the SQL
> Server system administrator password:  Configuring SQL Server...
> 
> /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: error while loading shared libraries:
> liblber-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory Created symlink
> /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mssql-server.service →
> /lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service. Setup has completed
> successfully. SQL Server is now starting.
```

When checking the status i get this

```
freak@loyaltie ~
$ systemctl status mssql-server --no-pager
× mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-02-24 01:50:54 EAT; 32s ago
   Duration: 7ms
       Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
    Process: 10553 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=exited, status=127)
   Main PID: 10553 (code=exited, status=127)
        CPU: 4ms
```

am using this operating system

```
$ neofetch
  `:oho/-`                                freak@loyaltie 
`mMMMMMMMMMMMNmmdhy-                      -------------- 
 dMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMs`                    OS: Parrot Security 6.0 (lorikeet) x86_64 
 +MMsohNMMMMMMMMMMMMMm/                   Host: 80YD Lenovo ideapad 320-14IKB 
 .My   .+dMMMMMMMMMMMMMh.                 Kernel: 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 
  +       :NMMMMMMMMMMMMNo                Uptime: 16 hours, 46 mins 
           `yMMMMMMMMMMMMMm:              Packages: 2812 (dpkg), 18 (snap) 
             /NMMMMMMMMMMMMMy`            Shell: bash 5.2.15 
              .hMMMMMMMMMMMMMN+           Resolution: 1920x1080, 1440x900 
                  ``-NMMMMMMMMMd-         DE: MATE 1.26.0 
                     /MMMMMMMMMMMs`       WM: Metacity (Marco) 
                      mMMMMMMMsyNMN/      Theme: air [GTK2/3] 
                      +MMMMMMMo  :sNh.    Icons: ara-dark [GTK2/3] 
                      `NMMMMMMm     -o/   Terminal: vscode 
                       oMMMMMMM.          CPU: Intel i5-7200U (4) @ 3.100GHz 
                       `NMMMMMM+          GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620 
                        +MMd/NMh          GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile 
                         mMm -mN`         Memory: 6609MiB / 11742MiB 
                         /MM  `h:
                          dM`   .                                 
                          :M-                                     
                           d:
                           -+
                            -
```

There are fewer logs from the terminal and i think its just a misconfiguration of the "servr" statement?

Comment: Have you addressed what appears in the error message? Have you also checked the logs to see if there's anything else?

Comment: Also, edit the question and include what operating system that you are using.

Comment: Is there a file named `liblber-2.4.so.2` anywhere on your system? It is part of OpenLDAP, and so at least in Debian it's within the `libldap` package. However, if the current version of Parrot is based on Debian 12, the `libldap-2.5-0` contains `liblber-2.5.so.0` which does not match the requirement. You may need to install an older version `libldap-2.4-2` [from the Parrot package repository](https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/pool/main/o/openldap/) to satisfy this requirement of `mssql`.